# Java cloner: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, javafx, clone

I have a Button event in witch I try to clone a model with [Rits](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning) cloning library. What I do is this:

```
lodgingForm.getAddButton().setOnAction(event -> addLodging());
```

and the addLodging:

```
private void addLodging() {
    Cloner cloner = new Cloner();
    Lodging lodging = cloner.deepClone(lodgingForm.getLodging());
    //Add Lodging to an observable list
}
```

running this code gives me a `NoClassDefFoundError`, here is the stack:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/BehaviorSkinBase$$Lambda$185/1931386975
at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor15.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
at com.rits.cloning.ObjenesisInstantiationStrategy.newInstance(ObjenesisInstantiationStrategy.java:17)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.newInstance(Cloner.java:272)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:437)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneArray(Cloner.java:473)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:429)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneObject(Cloner.java:449)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.cloneInternal(Cloner.java:432)
at com.rits.cloning.Cloner.deepClone(Cloner.java:302)
```

I don't see where is the error in my code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a very closely related [open issue](https://github.com/kostaskougios/cloning/issues/45) at the Rits project's GitHub page . I suggest you include your findings there and work through it with its other contributors.